# vim doesn't indent pascal code properly

Tags: pascal, indentation

I'm trying to indent a large pascal program, using VIM.

Searched Internet but didn't find nothing useful.

Discover that the last change in file pascal.vim was in 2011. This script file is supposed to indent a pascal code accordingly, but basic keywords like "begin", "if", "var", doesn't indent block codes after them.

When executing

```
gg=G
```

for example, to automatically indent all the code, it doesn't work.

I have already setted up the options "autoindent", "smartindent", "tabstop", "shiftwidth".

Comment: Sorry for delay. The project that I was working endded up, so the problem was closed. Thanks for comment.

Comment: "...  the last change in file pascal.vim was in 2011" - and the last change in the Pascal language itself was sometime in about 1852 :-)

Comment: :)). Yes, something like that.